# Generate Random Numbers with Std Dev x and Fixed Product

Tags: r, random

I want generate a series of returns x such that the standard deviation of the returns are say 0.03 and the product of 1+x = 1.  To summarise, there are two conditions for the returns:

1) `sd(x) == 0.03`

2) `prod(1+x) == 1`

Is this possible and if so, how can I implement it in R?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, can you give us an example that would satisfy your constraints?

Comment: Should the returns follow a particular distribution (normal? log-normal?) or can they follow any distribution? And how many should there be (that is, what is `length(x)`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slightly more sophisticated approach is to use knowledge of the log-normal distribution: from `?dlnorm`, Var= exp(2*mu + sigma^2)*(exp(sigma^2) - 1).  We want the geometric mean to equal 1, so the mean on the log scale should be 0.  We have `Var = exp(sigma^2)*(exp(sigma^2)-1)`, can't obviously solve this analytically but we can use `uniroot`:

Find the correct log-variance:

```
vfun <- function(s2,v=0.03^2) { exp(s2)*(exp(s2)-1)-v }
s2 <- uniroot(vfun,interval=c(1e-6,100))$root
```

Generate values:

```
set.seed(1001)
x <- rnorm(1000,mean=0,sd=sqrt(s2))
x <- exp(x-mean(x))-1   ## makes sum(x) exactly zero
prod(1+x)  ## exactly 1
sd(x)
```

This produces values with a standard deviation not exactly equal to 0.03, but close.  If we wanted we could fix this too ...

Answer (score 3):

A very simple approach is to simply simulate returns until you have a set that satisfies your requirements. You will need to specify a tolerance to your requirements, though (see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) why).

```
nn <- 10
epsilon <- 1e-3
while ( TRUE ) {
    xx <- rnorm(nn,0,0.03)
    if ( abs(sd(xx)-0.03)<epsilon & abs(prod(1+xx)-1)<epsilon ) break
}
xx
```

yields

```
[1]  0.007862226 -0.011437600 -0.038740969  0.028614022  0.006986953
[6] -0.004131429  0.030846398 -0.037977057  0.046448318 -0.025294236
```

Comment: Good answer, though note that if you don't want them to be roughly normally distributed you could try a different distribution. Furthermore, if you need a tolerance lower than about 1e-4, this will run for a very, very long time.

Comment: Suggestion- this will converge much faster and work for smaller error tolerances if you add the line `xx = .03 * xx / sd(xx)` after `xx` is generated. This fixes `sd(xx)` to be exactly `.03` (within floating point error), such that all you have to worry about is the product. Using this, I was able to get it within 1e-6 in just a few seconds.